# Unable to create bucket in Google Gloud Platform's Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a bucket in Google's Cloud Platform Storage. I am getting this weird error that I have no idea how to fix. Can someone help me figure this out?

[image]

Comment: How you creating the bucket?  Console, gcloud…

Comment: Please provide some details on how you are creating the bucket?

Comment: Can you please provide details mentioned in above comments?